# How can I get OSX split screen to work?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, interoperability, mac-os-x

OSX on Mac now allows two apps to split the screen.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948
Doesn't seem to work in Mathematica, even though the full-screen button displays an icon suggesting that it should.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** Mathematica 12.0 now supports this.

---

You can't.  This feature only works with certain programs and as of version 10.4 Mathematica is not one of them.  Maybe the coming Mac front end improvement mentioned in [this presentation](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9254/) will fix that, but this is purely a guess on my part.

As a workaround you can use window control software such as [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/), which makes it easy to arrange notebooks in a similar way to how the split-screen feature would.

Comment: I would recommend [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) for a similar functionality. It is a paid app since version 1.55, but older versions were free if you can find them somewhere.

Comment: Depending in the version, iirc if you start the spilt screen with a different app first, you can then choose MMA...which may be helpful for reading anf programming. However you cant start a split screen with two mma windows regardless of version natively in osx below version 12

Comment: @morbo That doesn't work for me ... The FE was only ported to Cocoa for M12.0.